# REVOKE database level DENY VIEW DEFINITION on object level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, security, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 environment:

We have the following statement:

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION TO Foo;
```

This operates on database level, so it will DENY the VIEW DEFINITION permission on ALL objects in the database.

That's clear so far.

What if for one object in that db, you still want Foo user to be able to view definition?

I tried to REVOKE the db level DENY on object level:

```
REVOKE VIEW DEFINITION ON OBJECT::[dbo].[storedProcFoo] FROM Foo;
```

Still the user cannot view definition.

I tried to GRANT it back on object level:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON OBJECT::[dbo].[storedProcFoo] TO Foo;
```

Still the user cannot view definition. (I know I have a DENY on database level, which take precedence, so i really did not expect to have it work like this)

Logically it should work:
DENY VIEW DEF on database level,
then REVOKE the DENY on few exceptional object in the database.

What am I missing here?
Please don't tell my i have to DENY VIEW DEF for all individual objects :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `DENY` and `REVOKE` are different things.  `DENY` is a explicit denial of the specified permission whereas `REVOKE` removes a previous `GRANT` or `DENY` that was previously granted.  A `REVOKE` has no effect if the exact specified permission doesn't already exist.  Your first REVOKE had no effect because you never granted permissions *at the object level*.

When conflicting `GRANT` and `DENY` permissions exist, `DENY` takes precedence.  If you choose to grant `VIEW DEFINITION` at a higher level, you must use `DENY` on the specific object exception, or `GRANT` permissions at the object level to only the needed objects.

To avoid this and reduce maintenance, you could grant `VIEW DEFINITION` at the schema level and create the procs you don't want `VIEW DEFINITION` on in a different schema.  The `GRANT` won't be inherited with this approach and you can avoid DENY entirely.  Personally, I think it best to avoid `DENY` whenever possible.